# What method should I use to write error messages to 'stderr' using 'printf' in a bash script?

Tags: bash, stderr, io-redirection, bash4

I want to direct the output of a `printf` in a `bash` script to `stderr` instead of `stdout`.

I am **not** asking about redirecting either `stderr` or `stdout` from where ever they are currently routed. I just want to be able to send the output from a `printf` to `stderr` instead of to the default of `stdout`.

I experimented a little and found that appending `1>&2` to the `printf`, as shown in the example below, appears to do what I want. However, I have ***no*** experience using bash. So my *primary* question is if there is a "*better*" way to do this in `bash`?

By "*better*" I mean is there another way to do this which is more commonly used, more conventional, or more idiomatic? How would a more experienced bash programmer do it?

```
#!/bin/bash
printf "{%s}   This should go to stderr.\n" "$(date)" 1>&2 
printf "[(%s)] This should go to stdout.\n" "$(date)"
```

I also have a *secondary* question. I am asking it not so much because I *need* to know, but more because I am just curious and would like to have a better understanding about what is happening.

It seems the above will only work when it runs inside a shell script. It does not appear to work when I try it from a command line.

Here is an example of what I mean.

```
irrational@VBx64:~$ printf "{%s} Sent to stderr.\n" "$(date)" 1>&2 2> errors.txt
{Sat Jun  9 14:08:46 EDT 2012} Sent to stderr.
irrational@VBx64:~$ ls -l errors.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 irrational irrational 0 Jun  9 14:39 errors.txt
```

I would expect the `printf` command above to have no output because the output should go to `stderr`, which in turn should go to a file. But this does not happen. Huh?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

First, yes, `1>&2` is the right thing to do.

Second, the reason your `1>&2 2>errors.txt` example doesn't work is because of the details of exactly what redirection does.

`1>&2` means "make filehandle 1 point to wherever filehandle 2 does currently" — i.e. stuff that would have been written to stdout now goes to stderr. `2>errors.txt` means "open a filehandle to `errors.txt` and make filehandle 2 point to it" — i.e. stuff that would have been written to stderr now goes into `errors.txt`. But filehandle 1 isn't affected at all, so stuff written to stdout still goes to stderr.

The correct thing to do is `2>errors.txt 1>&2`, which will make writes to both stderr and stdout go to `errors.txt`, because the first operation will be "open `errors.txt` and make stderr point to it", and the second operation will be "make stdout point to where stderr is pointing now".

Comment: Yes, indeed, `2>errors.txt 1>&2` is what I should have intended to use. I feel foolish in hindsight, but this seems to be one of those silly mistakes I have to keep making until the right way of doing it becomes "obvious" to me. ;-) Thanks much for the insight.

Answer (score 20):

1. That seems reasonable to me.  You don't need the `1`, though - it will work as is, but it's implied:

   ```
   printf "{%s}   This should go to stderr.\n" "$(date)" >&2
   ```
2. You have an order-of-operations problem:

   ```
   $ printf "{%s} Sent to stderr.\n" "$(date)" 2> errors.txt 1>&2
   $ ls -l errors.txt 
   -rw-r--r--  1 carl  staff  47 Jun  9 11:51 errors.txt
   $ cat errors.txt 
   {Sat Jun  9 11:51:48 PDT 2012} Sent to stderr.
   ```

Comment: +1.  See http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Redirections for more info.

Comment: My feeling is that `1>&2` is slightly less ambiguous than simply `>&2`.  No? (By that I mean, it more clearly states what's happening to a person looking at the script. bash obviously does not care.)

Comment: Sure, it's fine to have it - you just don't need it.

Comment: @irrationalJohn: You asked about idioms. Using `>&2` is more idiomatic than `1>&2`.

Answer (score 8):

The typical idioms are:

```
echo foo >&2           # you don't need to specify file descriptor 1
echo foo > /dev/stderr # more explicit, but wordier and less portable
```

Answer (score 5):

The question seems to indicate some confusion. You don't want to redirect stdout, you just want to have printf send its output to stderr... But to to that, you must use redirection.

The printf command always sends normal output to its stdout. That is what printf does. In order to achieve what you want, you have to have the shell arrange that stdout temporarily points to wherever you want the output to go. Notice that I say temporarily. When you type a command like

```
$ printf "Hello World!" >&2
```

the shell modifies the stdout handle for the duration of the execution of the printf statement. Then the shell restores the original value of stdout before it continues with the next command. In fact, if you want to redirect stdout permanently, you use the special command

```
$ exec >&2
```

After the shell has executed this, the shell no longer remembers the original value of the stdout handle.