# Bash script - redirect child script stderr to parent's stdout

Tags: linux, bash, redirect, stderr, subshell

I'm sure I'm missing something simple, but I'm using an executive script to call a few utility scripts and I want to handle all of the output from the utilities via one pipe. My issue is the utilities use stderr to report error conditions, but I can't capture that for use in the parent script.

Parent Script:

```
#!/bin/bash
child 2>&1 >/dev/null
```

Child Script

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Print"
echo "Error" 1>&2
```

What I expect is that the `stderr` of `child` (and all of it's commands) is redirected to `stdout` (hence no output), but when I execute `parent` I get `Error` echo'd to the terminal ("Print" is sent to /dev/null).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What's happening is that you're redirecting stderr to stdout's filehandle (perhaps /dev/stdout). Then you redirect stdout to /dev/null. However, stderr is still pointing to /dev/stdout.

To ignore all output, first redirect stdout, then redirect stderr to stdout

```
child >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Or, more simply since you're using bash specifically, redirect stdout and stderr together:

```
child &>/dev/null
```

Comment: Order of operations. Thanks, works great and I feel about as dumb as I thought I would.

Comment: Don't kick yourself, took me ages to grok that.

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer to the OP's question, but in case someone else is struggling to figure out **how to redirect a child process's output to the parent's `stdout`**, here it is.

```
#!/bin/bash
child &>>/dev/stdout &
```

This does the trick and will even work when backgrounding the child task as shown.

Thanks go to [@glenn jackman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7552/glenn-jackman) for being the first person in a day-long search for a solution to mention `/dev/stdout` in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19572808/1296733).

#### Update

Upon further research, with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10963704/1296733) being particularly helpful, it seems there's a way of doing this that also preserves the parent's `stderr`:

```
#!/bin/bash
child 1>&1 2>&2 &
```